# How to perform union of 2 lists?

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists ar1 and ar2.

`ArrayList ar1` contains a list of objects with each object having attributes ID, NAME and STATUS.
`ArrayList ar2` contains a list of objects with each object having attributes ID, NAME and SUBJECT.
Both ar1 and ar2 are of the same size.

Is there any way by which I can merge the two lists into a new list ar3 which contains a list of objects with each object having attributes ID, NAME, STATUS and SUBJECT?

**Update**: ID and NAME is same in both the lists.

Comment: You will have to write down a code to iterate through both the lists and create a third one.

Comment: 1. Add a good `hashcode()` and `equals` to your custom object. 2. Put both in a `HashSet` using `addAll()` 3. ???? 4 Profit

Comment: IS there any restriction on using 3rd party libs ?

Comment: commons.io has a tool for this.

Comment: I sort of agree with @jsn.  Write a good hashCode(), and equals() method, iterate through both and dump them into a Set, then from the set get a arrayList.

Comment: No there is no restriction on using 3rd party libs

Comment: @PeteBel, well, those objects are probably instances of different classes. Perhaps, both should extend from a base class. I don't know if my solution helps. Very limited information from OP.

Comment: Is there any limitation concerning duplicates?

Comment: Yes I dont want any duplicate records

Comment: @Jeroen Vanneve what is the tool that commons.io has?

Comment: @user2077648: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/ListUtils.html#union(java.util.List, java.util.List)

However, in the comments you made clear that duplicates shouldn't be allowed, so you'd have to throw the result into a set to remove duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
    List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("B", "C", "D",
            "E", "F"));
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    result = union(list1, list2);

    System.out.println(result);
}

public static List<String> union(List<String> list1, List<String> list2) {
    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();

    set.addAll(list1);
    set.addAll(list2);

    return new ArrayList<String>(set);
}
```

Output:

```
[D, E, F, A, B, C]
```

Comment: They objects in the lists are different types.

Comment: @MikeRylander Yes, before question was only about how to union two list.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, Target> map = new HashMap<>();

for (TypeWithStatus item : typesWithStatus) {
   map.put(item.getId()+item.getName(), createTypeWithStatusAndSubject(item));
}

for (TypeWithSubject item : typesWithSubject) {
   map.get(item.getId()+item.getName()).setSubject(item.getSubject());
}
```

The idea is to store all elements from the first list in a map and update the map values in a second run. This only works if both lists contain "the same" items in terms of id+name. If not, you'll have to add null checks.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understood correctly, you have a list of `A`s and a list of `B`s of same size, and you want a list of `C`s where the nth element is the union of the nth element of list a and the nth element of list B.

Well, first you need to define your union class:

```
class C {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    String status;
    String subject;

    C(A a, B b) {
        this.id = a.id;
        this.name = a.name;
        this.status = a.status;
        this.subject = b.subject;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use iterators:

```
Iterator<A> aIterator = aList.iterator();
Iterator<B> bIterator = bList.iterator();
List<C> cList = new ArrayList(aList.size());
while (aIterator.hasNext() && bIterator.hasNext()) {
    A a = aIterator.next();
    B b = bIterator.next();
    cList.add(new C(a, b));
}
```

Comment: Does not check for duplicat objects.

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, there is no need to.

Answer (score 0):

Use a search function with comparator C .

Define comparator as following

```
if(obja.id==objb.id & obja.name=objb.name) return (a==b);
```

So for every element in listA find the element in listB then you frame your new object and add

that in listC.